# X509* certificate serialization and deserialization in C

Tags: c, openssl, certificate, x509

I have a certificate in 509* format and I want to serialize it into a char buffer and then later desserialize it in other to recover the certificate 509* again.

I am doing it like this to serialize:

```
int size_cert = 0;
unsigned char* data;
BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
PEM_write_bio_X509(bio,certificate);
size_cert = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &data);
BIO_free(bio);
```

where data should have the certificate data!

To reconstruct the X509* certificate back from the data buffer I am doing this:

```
    BIO* bio;
    X509* cert;

    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_puts(bio, data);
    cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Where cert should get the certificate. This is not working properly, can some one give me a good example for this?

Comment: BIO_get_mem_data does not copy any memory. Once you free your BIO, the data is lost.

Comment: Are you not satisfied by DER format? Why you not consider DER format?

Comment: This is similar to what you want to do: [How to get PEM encoded X509 certificate as C++ string using openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877588/how-to-get-pem-encoded-x509-certificate-as-c-string-using-openssl). Its in C++ rather than C, though.

Comment: @mmm, Have u solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with the below code,

> 1 Load certificate to BIO using [BIO_read_filename](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_read_filename)
>
> 2 convert it to x509 using [PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX.html)
>
> 3 convert it to unsigned char* using [i2d_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_X509.html)
>
> 4 reconstruct the x509 from unsigned char* using [d2i_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_X509.html)

```
int main()
{   
    X509 *x509,*x509ser;    
    BIO *certBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());   
    char * path = "E:\\share\TempCert.pem"; // certificate path
    int len;
    unsigned char *buf;
    buf = NULL;

    BIO_read_filename(certBio, path); // reading certificate to bio
    x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(certBio, NULL, 0, NULL);  //converting to x509  
    len = i2d_X509(x509, &buf);  // converting to unsigned char*
    x509ser = d2i_X509(NULL, &buf, len); // converting back to x509 from unsigned char*

    BIO_free_all(certBio); 
    return 0;
}
```