# EVP_PKEY_keygen() generate key pair into a string?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

Here is the code snippet I have now and it is working well

```
/* Generate key */
if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0)
    goto cleanup;


// write rsa private key to file
bio_private = BIO_new_file("private_new.pem", "w+");
ret = PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(bio_private, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (ret != 1) {
    goto cleanup;
}
BIO_flush(bio_private);

// write rsa public key to file
bio_public = BIO_new_file("public_new.pem", "w+");

ret = PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio_public, pkey);
if (ret != 1) {
    goto cleanup;
}
BIO_flush(bio_public);
```

instead of using

```
PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(bio_private, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I want the generated key text to be put into a string and NOT a file. I don't want it written to disk, just to a string in memory.  Is there a PEM_ function to do this? or any other way?  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Very close to a duplicate of [How to get PEM encoded X509 certificate as C++ string using openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6877588/608639), [Convert OpenSSL x509 data to std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39968558/608639), [How to get PKCS7_sign result into a char * or std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38077226/608639), etc. They are using `std::strings` instead of C strings. If using C strings, then be careful of embedded NULLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
bio_private = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
```

instead of

```
bio_private = BIO_new_file("private_new.pem", "w+");
```

as seen [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BIO_new.html).

You can use [`long BIO_get_mem_data(BIO *b, char **pp)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BIO_get_mem_data.html) to access the data in the `BIO`:

> BIO_get_mem_data() sets pp to a pointer to the start of the memory BIOs data and returns the total amount of data available. It is implemented as a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Artjom's answer above. It worked! Here is the relevant code with the change :

```
/* Generate key */
if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0)
    goto cleanup;

// write private key to memory
bio_private = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
ret = PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(bio_private, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (ret != 1)
{
goto cleanup;
}
BIO_flush(bio_private);

BIO_get_mem_data(bio_private, &private_key_text);
cout << "PRIVE KEY :\n" << private_key_text << endl;
// write public key to memory
bio_public = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());    
ret = PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio_public, pkey);
if (ret != 1)
{
goto cleanup;
}
BIO_flush(bio_public);

BIO_get_mem_data(bio_public, &public_key_text);

cout << "PUBLIC KEY :\n" << public_key_text << endl;
```

Comment: If `private_key_text` is a binary representation of the key, then you cannot simply treat it as a string. Binary data may contain `\0` which is the string end character. So, it might happen that you print an incomplete key. The same goes for the public key.

Comment: you are right, but this is just to test that the code worked. I don't intend to print it out, I intend to use in-memory while the server is up and running, then re-generate it on re-start of the server. Thanks a lot!